# How do i get blob data posted to a php file and insert into the database?

Tags: php, ajax

I have managed to convert base64 image to blob image, and this works fine my question is how to post the blob image to php file and the insert it into the database... Here is my blob image example (blob:http%3A//localhost/acc6ed62-fa5c-4eaa-951e-9910eb57ad2f);
here is ajax code::

```
function Post_Image(){  
//This image has a base64 src           
var image = $('.img').attr('src');
var contentType = 'image/png';
var b64Data = image.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
//converting base64 to blob
var blob = b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType);
//The result from blobUrl= blob:http%3A//localhost/acc6ed62-fa5c-4eaa-951e-9910eb57ad2f
//This url will be posted to the server
var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);  
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('userImage', blobUrl);
$.ajax({
    url: 'wow.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {userImage:blobUrl},
    success:function(data){

    }
});
```

}

Comment: Why not send `data: {userImage:b64Data },` ?

Comment: @SugatoSengupta thanks man, i finally figured it out